# Angularjs two directives on one textbox

Tags: angularjs

I have two directives in a single textbox. One is datetimepicker and focus directive.

**DateTimePicker :**

```
app.directive('datetimepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          element.datetimepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd  hh:ii:ss",
            autoclose: true,
            todayBtn: true
          }).on('setDate', function(e) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
            scope.$apply();
          });
        }
    };
});
```

**Focus :**

```
app.directive('focus',function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope : {
            trigger : '@focus'
        },
        link : function(scope, elem,attrs) {
            var focusables = $(":focusable");
            scope.$watch('trigger', function(value) {
                if (value === "true") {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        elem[0].focus();
                    });                         
                }                           
            });
            elem.bind('keydown', function(e) {
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (code === 13) {
                    var current = focusables.index(this);
                    var next = focusables.eq(current + 1).length ? focusables.eq(current + 1) : focusables.eq(0);
                    next.focus();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
              });
        }
    };
});
```

This is my textbox

```
<input datetimepicker ng-model='dob' focus/>
```

I am getting the below error

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [focus, datepicker] asking for new/isolated scope on: <input datepicker="" ng-model="dob" focus="">
```

How to make these two directives work together in a textbox?

Comment: It seems that the `datepicker` directive is not the one you showed which is `datetimepicker`, can you update the question ?

Comment: i'm guessing this isn't the problem but just take notice that your directive is named datetimepicker and on your input your placing a datepicker. 

maybe there's a built in directive called datepicker or some other directive you have

Comment: Thanks @Omri. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to provide isolate scope manually to first directive because you don't need that so use `scope:false`, it will work so.

```
app.directive('datetimepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : '?ngModel',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          element.datetimepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd  hh:ii:ss",
            autoclose: true,
            todayBtn: true
          }).on('setDate', function(e) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
            scope.$apply();
          });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're getting is when at least two directives require new or isolated scopes.

As far as I can tell, your `focus` directive does not actually require isolated scope, as you can achieve `focus` using `attrs.trigger`.

Try to change your `focus` directive to:

```
app.directive('focus',function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link : function(scope, elem,attrs) {
            var focusables = $(":focusable");
            scope.$watch(attrs.trigger, function(value) {
                if (value === "true") {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        elem[0].focus();
                    });                         
                }                           
            });
            elem.bind('keydown', function(e) {
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (code === 13) {
                    var current = focusables.index(this);
                    var next = focusables.eq(current + 1).length ? focusables.eq(current + 1) : focusables.eq(0);
                    next.focus();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
              });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But for the first ENTER click, datetimepicker selecting the date, next click it is moving to the next textbox field instaed of selecting time.

Comment: @N123 Oh sorry, wasn't trying to fix the logic of the directive. Just to make it work and prevent the errors.